# Как в Laravel сделать валидацию числа?

Tags: php, laravel

Как в Laravel сделать валидацию числа формата типа как decimal(10,8) в MySql?

Answer (score 3):

В Laravel 5.* вы можете использовать валидацию с правилом 'between'. Это правило всегда рассматривает число как decimal. Просто укажите нужный интервал.

```
'required|numeric|between:0.01,99.99',
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-between